# Hadoop Pig or Streaming and Zip Files

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop-streaming

Using pig or hadoop streaming, has anyone loaded and uncompressed a zipped file? The original csv file was compressed using pkzip.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps because its mainly focused on using MapReduce in Java, but there is a ZipFileInputFormat available in hadoop. Its use via the Java API is described here:

http://cotdp.com/2012/07/hadoop-processing-zip-files-in-mapreduce/

The main part of this is the ZipFileRecordReader which uses Javas ZipInputStream to process each ZipEntry. The Hadoop reader is probably not going to work for you out of the box because it passes the file path of each ZipEntry as the key and the ZipEntry contents as the value.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, I already looked into this. I was hoping that someone out there created a custom PigStorage Loader that can do this for me instead of creating one on our own.

Comment: I would probably unzip your file before putting it on HDFS for processing unless you want to write a custom InputFormat for the file then. If you want it compressed you could use gzip since PigStorage works nicely with this format.

Comment: Pig's loader function uses Hadoop's InputFormat. It takes each record from the RecordReader and converts it to a tuple (or whatever), so if you want to  read zipped files you have to write your custom InputFormat/RecordReader anyhow.

Comment: I finally just created my own ZipInputFormat for this based on the link above. Now, I am trying to find a way to make the output filenames match the input filenames.